# xcodebuild archive does nothing in one folder but works fine in another

Tags: xcodebuild

This is really weird, I executed the following command in a folder created by my automated build, and it gets stuck after the SDK settings, and just sits there as if waiting for more input. but the same command works fine in another folder that I created by hand.

```
username$ xcodebuild -target RapidApps -archivePath ~/Documents/RapidApps.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos8.1 -scheme "RapidApps" -configuration "Release" archive
User defaults from command line:
    IDEArchivePathOverride = /Users/username/Documents/RapidApps.xcarchive

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos8.1
```

anything i can do to figure out what the command is doing and why it's not proceeding?

Answer (score 1):

just faced the same issue and found the solution [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24874)

TL;DR The scheme that you are trying to use should be shared. Else xcodebuild will try to generate all the possible scheme and timeout.

Comment: Turning on the `Shared` option under `Edit Scheme` worked perfectly for me! I'm using Team City for continuous integration, and the build was hanging. Again, this solved that problem completely. Thank you @MichaelLoo